# HTML5 roadmap & issue tracker

Tags: html

I was searching whether there is a some kind of a roadmap for HTML5. Also whether there is an issue tracker. I could only find the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).

I am especially interested in **drag API**. Whether it would ever support ghost image that is opaque and [movement constraints just like jquery](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement) does.

**Questions**

1. Is there a roadmap for HTML 5?
2. Where can raise a feature request?

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://caniuse.com/ ? It might have some useful information for you.

Comment: Great, thanks. There is also a link to an issue tracker on github.

Comment: Yep there usually is. It's a great webpage for this stuff!

Comment: The HTML5 issue tracker is at https://github.com/w3c/html/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add my comment as an answer if anybody else finds this question through Google or something and perhaps doesn't read comments on original question.

You can find a lot of useful information (browser support, issue trackers etc) @ http://caniuse.com/